# update @form não funcionando, Java EE

Tags: java-ee

Ja tentei com as opções @form, :matricula, matricula_form... e nada.

Quando excluo a matricula do banco, apenas após atualizar a página ela some, estou esquecendo de algo???

Segue abaixo código "matricula_lista"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<p:commandButton value="Nova Matricula"
    action="#{matriculaBean.novaMatricula}" update="matricula_form"
    icon="novo-icon" />


<p:dataTable value="#{matriculaBean.matriculas}" var="matricula"
    style="margin-top:10px; width:100%" emptyMessage="Nenhuma matrícula cadastrada">

    <p:column headerText="Número" width="40" style="text-align:center;">

        <h:outputText value="#{matricula.numero}" />

    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Aluno" width="220" style="text-align:center;" >

        <h:outputText value="#{matricula.aluno.nome}" />

    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Curso" width="120" style="text-align:center;">

        <h:outputText value="#{matricula.curso.nome}" />

    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Data" sortBy="#{matricula.dataCriacao}" width="80" style="text-align:center;">
        <h:outputFormat value="#{matricula.dataMatricula}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </h:outputFormat>

    </p:column>

    <p:column width="50" style="text-align:center">

        <p:commandButton icon="editar-icon"
            action="#{matriculaBean.editar(matricula)}" update=":matricula_form" />
        <p:commandButton icon="excluir-icon" action="#{matriculaBean.excluir(matricula)}"
                    style="color:red; margin-left:20px;" update="@form" />

    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score -1):

As vezes (que não sei explicar exatamente pq :D) o javascript da página desabilita.

Uma opção seria atualizar o componente via bean da página.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("id_componente");
```